# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError while accessing dll method in Java

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I want to load dll file and invoke dll methods in java. Have tried with 2 variants : loadLibrary & registering dll in windows. Unfortunately, both doesn't work to me.

Using System.loadLibrary:

```
public class App {
    static {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("abc");
            System.loadLibrary("xyz");      
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
          System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
          System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    public static native double gamma(double x);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App().gamma(10.1);
    }
```

I got below exception while running the above program.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: App.gamma(D)D
        at App.gamma(Native Method)
        at App.main(App.java:26)
```

---

Trying to registering dll files using regsvr32 and get access in java.

```
C:\Windows\System32>regsvr32 /in abc.dll
C:\Windows\System32>regsvr32 /in xyz.dll
```

If i enter above command in cmd means, i got following message.
*The module "D:\abc.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.*

And also, dont know how to access system registered dll methods in java in this case.

Comment: Did you use javah to generate the header file for jvm ?

Comment: `regsvr32` only works for COM libraries.

Comment: @neohope Yeah.. had generated.

Comment: try `System.load("path://.../abc.dll")`

Comment: @progy_rock, have tried, but also getting the same exception. :(

Comment: I don't know what's happening. I tried defining the main method as `public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsatisfiedLinkError { ... }` and tried using `System.load()` but I got the same error :'-(

Comment: @Vasu you do not need to register the dll to load it in JVM.  Can you print the stack trace? Because there are more than one reason for java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError. Ex. 1.JVM can not find the dll 2.JVM can not find the exported function in the dll 3.JVM loads the dll more than once. 4.You dll depends on other dlls which are missing.

Comment: Registering the DLL with Windows is futile. The DLL was found by `loadLibrary()`, otherwise you would have got an exception at that point. The problem is in the method signature. It doesn't agree with what would currently be generated by `javah` from the current .class file. Check that your .c and .h files agree, and that your .h file is as current as the corresponding .class file.

Comment: And it's unclear why you would instantiate an `App` just to call a static method.